# reference to view property is retaining the view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I am having memory leaks when I m using a view controller's view
My code sequence is like this

```
 viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   destinationViewController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
   [destinationViewCOntroller useView:viewController1.view];
   [viewController1 release];
   [destinationViewController release];
```

And for testing purpose I have empty implementation in useView method. So my problem is viewController1 is never getting deallocated. I have made sure that no other place has any reference to viewController1. 
When I remove the method call(useView) where I pass viewcontroller1.view then viewcontroller1 is deallocating properly.
Any ideas why the behaviour is like this?

Comment: How did you check that vc1 does not get deallocated?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a rather academic problem. Just enable ARC and forget about it.